# Create NUnit test cases automatically from Pex

Tags: command-line, nunit, pex

I need to create the NUnit Test case automatically from my .Net Solution file.
Morover this needs to be done , from command line.
I heard Pex create test cases automatically.
Let know

Answer (score 3):

The following steps should get you there:

1. Add a reference to Pex.NUnit.dll in your test project
2. In your test project's AssemblyInfo.cs, add the attribute - `[assembly: Pex.NUnit.PexNUnitPackage]`
3. Build your solution (either from Visual Studio or using msbuild from the command line)
4. run Pex from the command line: `pex.exe bin\Debug\TestProjectName.dll`
5. The tests are placed under `reports\TestProjecName.#####.#####\tests`.

You can read more about this in Exercise 5 of [Parameterized Unit Testing with Microsoft Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/pextutorial.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

[Ryan Gross](https://stackoverflow.com/users/428972/ryan-gross)' answer
points to the right direction.

However **Pex.exe** generates [Unit Tests](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/pex/wiki/Unit%20Testing.html) from [Parameterized Unit
Tests](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/pex/wiki/parameterized%20unit%20testing.html), not from
application classes itself.

To generate [Parameterized Unit Tests](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/pex/wiki/parameterized%20unit%20testing.html) you need to run [pexwizard.exe](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/pex/wiki/Pex%20Wizard.html)

```
pexwizard.exe <your assembly name> options
```

Possible options are described in
http://testoriented.googlecode.com/svn-history/r89/suitability/trunk/Tools/Pex-0.22.50128.1/pexwizard.txt