# Pex (not Moles) in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, pex

I'm looking for the Pex Addin for VS 2012 (or its equivalent).

I know Moles became Fakes (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx) which is present. I want the Pex part as input generator for automated WhiteBox testing. I'm not sure how I can do this within VS2012. Could someone give me a pointer here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how-to-use-pex-in-visual-studio-2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490116/how-to-use-pex-in-visual-studio-2012)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Pex Team say](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) that they're going to build a new release of Pex, but the simultaneous move from Moles to Fakes is causing 'some changes to how things work internally, and is delaying the next release of Pex'.

One of the contributors [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422153/can-i-use-pex-with-visual-studio-2012) got some information from Microsoft saying that they expect the academic licence to be available in early 2013.

Comment: You should just link to other question and flag this question as duplicate, rater than answer it.see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled

Answer (score 1):

Finally Pex has something for Visual Studio 2012: Code Digger (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fb5badda-4ea3-4314-a723-a1975cbdabb4). You can ask it to generate a input / output table, with parameters that will cover all your code.

However, it supports only Portable Libraries projects today... let's wait for new releases.

Comment: The Portable Libraries limit can now be disabled but I can't seem to generate anything on even the simplest of code.