# Can't find Run Pex in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, pex

I installed Pex on my Windows 7 and when I right click on a piece of code in VS2013, I can't see the option "Run Pex".
please Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please see my reply to the question [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599771/how-can-i-get-pex-to-auto-generate-unit-tests

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use PEX in Visual Studio 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490116/how-to-use-pex-in-visual-studio-2012)

Answer (score 0):

The Pex page on research.microsoft.com has a link suggesting that you use Code Digger on VS2012 & VS2013. You can find the link at: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/downloads.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could find "`Generate Inputs/Outputs Table`" menu item, when you open you .cs file and right click inside method body.