# How can I get PEX to auto-generate unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, automated-tests, pex

How I can get PEX to auto-generate unit tests in Visual Studio 2013?

I can auto-generate unit tests with PEX in visual studio 2010 and the menu was found by right clicking in the function body.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use PEX in Visual Studio 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490116/how-to-use-pex-in-visual-studio-2012)

Answer (score 3):

We did not release a version for Visual Studio 2013.
The good news is that you can now do that same auto-generation of unit tests in Visual Studio 2015 using the "Smart Unit Tests" feature.

Comment: The good news would be to deploy that on VS2013 to use that at work !

Comment: and for VB.NET solutions?

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2013, they do provide PEX framework (lightweight version) named as CodeDigger.

But CodeDigger is limited that it just generates a table of all the possible combinations of inputs and output.

No options to copy that table or Save any of the test suites.

CodeDigger gives a minimal help. Not so great